# How to get one line from a print output in linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, sed, subprocess

I'm trying to pull one line from a subprocess.check_output but so far I have no luck. I'm running a Python script and this is my code:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("sox /home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat", shell=True)
```

and this is what I get back when I run the script:

```
Samples read:             80000
Length (seconds):      5.000000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.001129
Minimum amplitude:    -0.006561
Midline amplitude:    -0.002716
Mean    norm:          0.000291
Mean    amplitude:    -0.000001
RMS     amplitude:     0.000477
Maximum delta:         0.002930
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.000052
RMS     delta:         0.000102
Rough   frequency:          272
Volume adjustment:      152.409
```

Now I want to get the 9th line (RMS amplitude) out of this list. I already tried something with sed but it didnt gave anything back:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("sox /home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^RMS     amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p0'",stderr= subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Thank You

Comment: Why can't the output be parsed to get the 9th line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about grep-ing the line ?

```
output = subprocess.check_output("sox /home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | grep 'RMS     amplitude:'",stderr= subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might that you're matching for spaces, but `sox` is actually outputting a tab characters to do the column spacing. Your terminal is likely expanding the tab to spaces, so when you copy/paste the output, you see spaces. Try matching for `[[:space:]]` (any whitespace character) instead of literal spaces:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("sox /home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat | sed -n 's#^RMS[[:space:]]*amplitude:[[:space:]]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'", shell=True)
```

I also had to remove the `0` after the `p` at the end of your sed replace command.

You could also do the output processing in Python (using `re`) rather than spinning off another subprocess to execute the `sed` command. That would probably be easier to debug.

Comment: When I put your code in it gave me the whole list and not only the RMS amplitude, but still thanks, it worked with using grep

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your line, you need to remove the 0 at the end and escape the '\1':

```
output = subprocess.check_output("sox /home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^RMS     amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\\1#p'",stderr= subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Also using a pipe isn't really advisable, security wise, I'd suggest changing this line to:

```
p      = subprocess.Popen(('sox', '/home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav', '-n', 'stat', '2>&1'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('sed', '-n', 's#^RMS     amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\\1#p'), stdin=p.stdout)
p.wait()
```